# parallel iteration in lua

Tags: for-loop, lua, iteration, torch

I would like to for-loop through multiple tables in parallel in Lua. I could just do:

```
for i in range(#table1)
  pprint(table1[i])
  pprint(table2[i])
end
```

But I'd rather something like python's `zip`:

```
for elem1, elem2 in zip(table1, table2):
  pprint(elem1)
  pprint(elem2)
end
```

Is there such a thing in standard Lua (or at least in whatever comes packaged with torch?).

Comment: Nothing in the standard libraries. I don't know about torch. But you can write your own iterator to do this easily enough.

Comment: Take a look at Moses library: http://yonaba.github.io/Moses/doc/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want something in Lua that's similar to some Python function, you should look at [Penlight](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight) first. For this specific case there is the [`seq.zip`](http://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.seq.html#zip) function. It [seems](https://github.com/torch/distro/tree/master/extra) that Penlight is installed together with Torch, but you can also get it via LuaRocks (which again is bundled with at least one Torch distribution).

Anyway, the `seq.zip` function in Penlight only supports zipping two sequences. Here is a version that should behave more like Python's `zip`, i.e. allowing more (or less) than two sequences:

```
local zip
do
  local unpack = table.unpack or unpack
  local function zip_select( i, var1, ... )
    if var1 then
      return var1, select( i, var1, ... )
    end
  end

  function zip( ... )
    local iterators = { n=select( '#', ... ), ... }
    for i = 1, iterators.n do
      assert( type( iterators[i] ) == "table",
              "you have to wrap the iterators in a table" )
      if type( iterators[i][1] ) ~= "number" then
        table.insert( iterators[i], 1, -1 )
      end
    end
    return function()
      local results = {}
      for i = 1, iterators.n do
        local it = iterators[i]
        it[4], results[i] = zip_select( it[1], it[2]( it[3], it[4] ) )
        if it[4] == nil then return nil end
      end
      return unpack( results, 1, iterators.n )
    end
  end
end

-- example code (assumes that this file is called "zip.lua"):
local t1 = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14 }
local t2 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" }
for a, b, c in zip( {ipairs( t1 )}, {ipairs( t2 )}, {io.lines"zip.lua"} ) do
  print( a, b, c )
end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Python-like zip() iterator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function zip(...)
  local arrays, ans = {...}, {}
  local index = 0
  return
    function()
      index = index + 1
      for i,t in ipairs(arrays) do
        if type(t) == 'function' then ans[i] = t() else ans[i] = t[index] end
        if ans[i] == nil then return end
      end
      return unpack(ans)
    end
end

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Example use:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

a = {'a','b','c','d'}
b = {3,2,1}
c = {7,8,9,10,11}

for a,b,c,line in zip(a,b,c,io.lines(arg[0])) do
  print(a,b,c,line)
end

print '\n--- Done! ---'
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a version with variable number of lists based on the other responses and added coroutines, it's not the fastest but I think it's very readable. I'm gonna use it but maybe someone else also finds it usefull.

Also this was made for use with neovim's **LuaJit**.

```lua
local zipgen = function(args)
    -- find smallest iterator's size
    local min = #args[1]
    for i = 2, #args, 1 do
        min = #args[i] < min and #args[i] or min
    end

    -- create list with 'i'th element from all iterators
    for i=1, min do
        local ans = {}
        for j=1, #args do
            -- get 'j'th iterator's 'i'th element
            ans[j] = args[j][i]
        end

        -- return list of 'i'th elements
        coroutine.yield(unpack(ans))
    end
end

-- python like zip iterator
zip = function(...)
    local args = {...}
    -- return a function that resumes the coroutine when called
    return coroutine.wrap(function() zipgen(args) end)
end
```